# SharePoint: Https WebClient Request occurred "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"

Tags: https, credentials, 401

I had the below code in a `SharePoint Webpart` and it worked properly:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    wb.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    var data = wb.DownloadData(@"http://sharepointSite/_layouts/15/Resources/Stamps/image.png");
}
```

If I try to use `https` in browser like:

```
https://sharepointSite/_layouts/15/Resources/Stamps/image.png
```

After entering the credential I can download it:

but the problem is where I try to use `https` in my code:

```
 using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    wb.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    var data = wb.DownloadData(@"https://sharepointSite/_layouts/15/Resources/Stamps/image.png");
}
```

and I've got error:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

I will give my two cents!

Not sure what SharePoint version this is ? On Premises or Cloud ?

Make sure the sharepoint account(the current user of the site) has access to this image.
In your code after initialising WebClient , use **webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;**.

Also, prefix @ in front of the URL
e.g. **@"https://sharepointSite/_layouts/15/Resources/Stamps/image.png"**

Let me know how you go.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Thank you Ravi. It's SharePoint 2013 and installed in the local network on windows server 2013. the url is sample but you must know it works with http and `webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true` . I don't know how can I solve it in `https`.